# How Do I Copy The Cell Containing a Substring?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of alphanumeric inventory items in Column A.  They are sorted ascending by value.

In Column B, I have an unsorted list of the inventory items filenames.

I'd like to place a formula in Column C that finds the cell in Column B that contains a substring that matches Column A.

I've experimented with several forms of VLOOKUP and INDEX/MATCH, but the best I've gotten is an index number of the matching cell.  That isn't quite what I need, but its the closest I've gotten.

I'd really like to get the entire value of the cell in Column B.

Answer (score 0):

I know of one way to do this, and one additional resource that might make your life much easier.

First, If I had the index of the matching cell, I would simply use an `indirect` function. They're used like this:

```
indirect("string reference to a cell")
```

In your case, cell C1 would contain

```
=indirect("A" & B1)
```

---

Second, the resource I have in mind is something I read long, long ago, but stuck in my mind as absolutely brilliant. It uses the `lookup` function, which only exists for backwards compatibility but has turned out to have hidden utility. See [this MrExcel.com page](http://www.mrexcel.com/pc18.shtml) for more info. Barry Houdini's answer is, to prevent link rot, repeated here without the question itself: `=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(D$2:D$10,A2),E$2:E$10)`